# Random number in a skew normal distribution (equivalent to NORMINV())

Tags: excel, statistics, distribution

I'm trying to create a skewed random number generator using a skew normal distribution, but I don't know how to turn my formula (which uses `NORMDIST()`) into a `NORMINV()`-based formula that can generate the numbers I want. This is my formula:

```
=2/s * NORMDIST((x-m)/s, 0, 1, 0) * NORMSDIST(k*(x-m)/s)
```

Where "x" is the number, "s" is the scale, "m" is the location, and "k" is the shape. I admit I found the formula [online](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/569764-skew-normal-distribution.html), but it seems to do what I want to do, except the wrong way around.

How can I do this?

Comment: Not clear to me what exactly you are trying to achieve. Nobody answers, so I think I'm not the only one. Maybe this http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/477702-generating-skewed-normal-distribution-random-numbers.html?

Comment: The equation in the Mr Excel link worked for me.    That was this equation =NORMDIST(D5,B$2,B$1,False)*NORMDIST(D5*skew,B$2,B$1,True)*2    Note that the first function is the probability density function (because of the False), the second is the second is the cumulative density function (because of the True)      Note that I just wanted to create a skewed normal distribution in Excel, I wasn't attempting to use any kind of random numbers

Answer (score 3):

Adelchi Azzalini has a [page](http://azzalini.stat.unipd.it/SN/faq-r.html) on how to generate pseudo-random numbers with skew-normal (SN) distribution.  Here from the page:

[image: SN random numbers]

The N(0,1) variates u0 and v in step 1. can be calculated in Excel as `NORMINV(RAND(),0,1)`.  And δ expressed in terms of shape parameter α is `δ = α/SQRT(1+α*α)`.

Note: Python's SciPy is in the process of getting a skew-normal random variable (`scipy.stats.skewnorm`), see [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.18.0rc2/scipy/stats/_continuous_distns.py#L4566) in SciPy 0.18.0rc2 code.  The [docs](http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.stats.skewnorm.html) reference a paper by Azzalini and Capitanio and the same page I referenced above.